# Enum flags combined with Dictionary

Tags: list, optimization, dictionary, enum-flags

Could not find a simple way to define my problem, but I will try to explain it as best I can.

I need to be able to represent a selection of predefined items, I have many thousands of these instances of selections in the program, and need a single value that can represent the selection of items per instance (many selections will repeat).

My first solution using Enum's seem okay at this point, but I seem to have a problem... Enum flags are represented as one bit per unique item and 64 bits are the maximum that the language can deal with for Enum's (C#), and I have an arbitrary number of values that need to be set and unset.

Example Solution 1:

```
//Two dimensional map of instances
Instances[,]

//Item Enum Flags
Items { 0, 1, 2, 4 }

//Setting the selection
Instances[1000,1000].Selection.Set(Items.1)
Instances[1000,1000].Selection.Set(Items.2)

Instances[1000,1000].Selection.IsSet(Items.1) = true
Instances[1000,1000].Selection.IsSet(Items.2) = true
```

My second solution would be to build a list of selections and use an ID number to reference this selection in the instances.

Example Solution 2:

```
//Two dimensional map of instances
Instances[,]

//Dictionary 
Dictionary<ID, List<Item>> Selections

//Enum for items (not flags)
Item { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }

//Item list add
List<Item> Items
Items.Add(Item.0)      
Items.Add(Item.1)

//Add Items to selections
Selections.Add(Items)

//Setting the selection
Instances[1000,1000].Selection = //ID of item list in Selections

//See if item is within selection
Selections[Instances[1000,1000].Selection].Contains(Item.1)
```

The requirements of the solution is to be low memory usage (I am developing this for a mobile application), Ease of use (I need to be able to edit it on the fly).

Which solution would be best, taking into consideration my requirements and 
How can I accomplish this, or simplify it to meet my requirements?

Comment: It depends. Are all 2^n possibilities equally likely to occur or is there some nice property (such as "usually few are set at once" or "the set items usually form long runs") to exploit?

Comment: @harold No it is completely random and set by user input on where they are set, but usually (not always) where they are set they will be repeated in a selected area. I guess you could think of it as painting areas with the selection items being the colours selected, and the two dimensional array as the canvas.

Comment: Ok then I have a different idea: a quad-tree for every item. That would compress the areas nicely.